# Can i set logging level of all loaded modules at once?

Tags: python, logging

- main module
- module A
- module B

The main module uses the functions of modules.
The functions of modules include logger.info or logger.warning.. so on to show what i made wrong about the code.

**Objective** : 
- Logging all things in main, A and B.
- A faculty to set logging level of A and B in main jupyter notebook, at the moment. (e.g. When i need more information about a function of A, then increase logging level to *DEBUG* from *INFO*)

By the way, the main script has:

```
import logging, sys

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
fh = logging.FileHandler('process.log')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s\n')

# add formatter to ch
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

I want to use Logger object and configure this object, instead of logging's baseconfig. But if i can't, other ways is ok.

Comment: If you do `logging.getLogger('logger')` into `Module A` and `Module B`, then they should have access to the same `logger` as your main file. From there, you can set whatever level at any time you want.

Comment: Most loggers set their logger name to the package name, so you can usually just `getLogger("some_package")` and add handlers/set levels/etc on it

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. I wish you would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
```

Into Module A and Module B, then they should have access to the same logger as your main file. From there, you can set whatever level at any time you want. E.g.

```
# ../module_a.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('logger')

# Now all instances of "logger" will be set to that level.
# Except for those for which the logging level was
# explicitly set (actually very rare case).
logger.setLevel(whatever)
```

Basically, loggers are globally registered by name and accessible through the logging module directly from any other modules.